# Why I'm getting an invalid column reference in SQL query?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to run the following SQL query in Hive:

```
with x as (
select ci 
from imp 
where ai = '589867' 
and dt = '20210925'
) 
select count(*),dt, ce.c_name 
from x join c_entity ce 
on x.ai = ce.ai 
group by dt,ce.c_name
```

I'm getting an "Invalid column reference 'ai' error in Hive. 'ai' is definitely a valid column in both tables imp and ce.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: But `x` projected away all columns except `ci` in its defining `select`, so it doesn't matter that `imp` had an `ai` column.

Answer (score 0):

cte is not returning ai column, so you have to add it to your cte output and I think dt as well.

```
with x as (
select ci , ai , dt
from imp 
where ai = '589867' 
and dt = '20210925'
) 
select count(*),dt, ce.c_name 
from x join c_entity ce 
on x.ai = ce.ai 
group by dt,ce.c_name
```